# React Hooks Second Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a EventTable component that displays a table and one of the cells in the table contains another component called EventDialog and i want to be able to press a button that opens the FullScreenDialog button shows the dialog screen and makes an API call.
The issue that I am facing is the API call is made only once the page is rendered in the parent component and not when the button is pressed.

This is the EventTable.js

This is the FullScreenDialog.js

```
export default function FullScreenDialog(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://localhost:44392/api/events/${props.rowId}`)
        .then(res => {
            setCountries(res.data);
            console.log(res.data)
            setLoad(true);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            setError(err.message);
            setLoad(true)
        })
}, []);

console.log(props.rowId)

  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` should observer whether `open` variable changed. So, each time that `open` is set to true, API call should be made.

Your `useEffect` code should look like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      axios.get(`https://localhost:44392/api/events/${props.rowId}`)
        .then(res => {
            setCountries(res.data);
            console.log(res.data)
            setLoad(true);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            setError(err.message);
            setLoad(true)
        })
   }
}, [open]);
```